# How to pass a user input and update the data using Vue-SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-sweetalert2

I'm currently trying to make a "create" button that triggers a popup with a user text input as the attached image below.

[image: popup]

If it works as I intend, it should store the name written in the text field when the OK button is clicked, and then the name should be reflected on the page like below, as I typed my own name 'Shinichi' as the input.

```
Test result of createCustomer: Shinichi
```

But in reality, what is displayed is the hardcoded Object which is defined in the alertDisplay() method in the code below.

```
Test result of createCustomer: { "params": { "title": "What is your Name?", "input": "text", "inputPlaceholder": "Enter your name here", "showCloseButton": true } }
```

[image: ObjectDisplayed]

```
<template>
      <v-btn class="create-button" color="yellow" @click="alertDisplay">Create</v-btn>

    <br/>

    <p>Test result of createCustomer: {{ createdCustomer }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        createdCustomer: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      alertDisplay() {
        var customer = this.$swal({
                          title: 'What is your Name?',
                          input: 'text',
                          inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your name here',
                          showCloseButton: true,       
                        });
        console.log(customer);
        this.createdCustomer = customer; 
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How can I pass the name and have it displayed on the screen instead of the Object like in the attached image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use promises to get the user input of a swal modal.

```
async alertDisplay() {
    let customer = await this.$swal({
        title: 'What is your Name?',
        input: 'text',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your name here',
        showCloseButton: true,       
    });
    console.log(customer)
}
```

You can see it in this Codepen found on the documentation : 
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true

Comment: How about if the field must not be empty? How can one set required?